# How to find the control of textbox inside the grid

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using ASP.NET and I have one `GridView` that has a `TextBox` within an editTemplate, but I am not able to find the control; whenever I try to assign the value to `TextBox` of `GridView` I'm getting a `NullReferenceException`.

My code is as follows:

```
for (int i = 0; i < grdTransfer.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    GridViewRow row = grdTransfer.Rows[i];
    if (((CheckBox)row.FindControl("chkSelect")).Checked)
    {
        count = 1;
        (row.FindControl("txtDestLocation") as TextBox).Text = txtLocation.Text;
    }
}
```

Issue: `NullReferenceException: object reference not set to the instance of an object`.

This means I'm getting `null` whenever I try to assign the value of `GridView` `TextBox` from outside the `TextBox` at runtime.

***What am I doing wrong?***

Comment: 1. Are you adding "txtDestLocation" dynamically? 2. On which event are you trying to execute this code?

Comment: yes i m adding txtDestLocation dynamically

Answer (score 1):

A couple things.

1. WHere is the error happening, I see two likely places.
2. Does the grid have a header or footer?  You aren't checking for either one?
3. Why aren't you doing this stuff as part of the [GridView.RowDataBound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound.aspx) event?

Comment: Along with header row also check for footer row if its there. Otherwise last iteration of loop will raise this error again.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are getting this exception on the very last loop.

Grid Row collection index start from Zero but the count will return the total number of row. So you should use count -1 while looping through...

`for (int i = 0; i < grdTransfer.Rows.Count -1; i++)`..

I would prefer using foreach(GridViewRow row in grdTransfer.Rows) instead.

Comment: +1 for mentioning using foreach, -1 for thinking you need to subtract 1 from Count (he's using less than operator).

Comment: @tster Nice catch :) I didn't realised he is using <.